# How to programmatically upload files to Telegram?

Tags: linux, backup, automation, upload, telegram-messenger

Since Telegram is an [infinite cloud service](https://superuser.com/questions/1039103/total-file-quota-on-telegram/1367438#1367438), I use it as a secondary backup location. I would like to automate this so that I don't have to remember to do it every month (in the last two years I missed about every second monthly backup).
But I can't find a way to automate any Telegram client without click macros (I would like to have it run silently in the background):

- `./Telegram --help` does nothing except opening the program.
- I wasn't successful in determining where the `argv` variable goes from the [main method](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/dev/Telegram/SourceFiles/main.cpp), so I don't know if there even are console arguments.
- Bots can't access my file system (and that's a good thing).

I can easily automate packing the files I want into 1.5GB archives using 7z, but I have no idea about how to actually send them. Is there a way to do it without click macros?

I'm on Debian 9.5 and using the official Linux client from telegram.org.

Comment: Can't you directly use the libmtproto to write a storage backend?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know that program. Also, I would have to know details about how to send packages to the Telegram servers. At some point I just have a custom client. If you know how to make a minimalistic program for that or whatever your idea was, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't know the details, but it seems that [TDlib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) is what you want.

Comment: It seems like there is a command line client for Telegram and it can send files, even though it's not in the documentation: https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/458 I'll try that this evening and if it works, write an answer.

Comment: Update: The command line arguments are now officially documented and indeed, there is no way to do it with the official client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! The official client probably doesn't allow it (all known command line arguments are unofficially documented [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/2058)), but for Linux and Mac (and probably also Linux subsystem on Windows), there is an unofficial command line interface for Telegram called "tg": https://github.com/vysheng/tg
It doesn't mention in its description that it can also send files, but in [a Github issue](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/458#issuecomment-86625049) someone wrote that there is the `send_file` function. In general it's not too well documented, but calling it with `--help` and entering `help` inside the program gives a lot of info, the rest can be figured out by fiddling with the parameters and trying different things.
This is the solution I came up with that way:

### Preparation

- Install tg like the readme file says. It didn't work rightaway for me on Debian due to a bug, but as said in [this bug report comment](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/1547#issuecomment-415848452), installing `libssl1.0-dev` is a workaround for that bug: Execute `sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev` between `./configure` and `make`.
- Log in with your Telegram account: `bin/telegram-cli` to start the interactive program, enter phone number (with country code, so in my case starting with `+49`), enter login code.
- Now use another Telegram client to send a message in the target chat (or alternatively receive a message there). That adds the chat's name to the program's internal chat list. If multiple chats with the same name exist, it seems to pick the most recently added one. I have not found a way to message a chat by ID.
  That's it for the setup, `quit` exits the program.

### Uploading files programmatically

Now files can be uploaded by giving a `send_file` command to the program with `--execute`, which makes it execute that command and then quit automatically:

```
/path/to/tg/bin/telegram-cli --exec 'send_file <chat> <filename>'
```

`<chat>` is the chat's name.
`<filename>` is the path to the file.
`/path/to/tg` should be obvious.

### Example usage

I'll use something like this to upload a backup of my Google Drive folder to Telegram after I've created it with p7zip:

```
for filename in ~/drive_backup/drive.zip.*; do ~/tg/bin/telegram-cli --exec 'send_file Backup_chat '"$filename"; done
```

This uploads all files whose names start with "`drive.zip.`" (.001, .002 etc.) in the folder `~/drive_backup` to the Telegram chat "Backup_chat".

Comment: The message in telegram is "Saved Messages" to my own chat. When i run "bin/telegram-cli --exec 'send_file "Saved Messages" config.log'  nothing happens. Is there a way we can name this as Backup_chat.

Comment: @Suresh You need your own username, without quotes. So in my case it would be `msg @Fabian42 "test"` or `msg @Fabian42 test`. Sadly it gives you no feedback if you have the wrong username or one for which the program hasn't seen a message come in or out yet.

Comment: That is already the preparation step #3 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload encrypted backups on Telegram cloud with [PGPgram](https://github.com/tallero/PGPgram). It uses `gpg` for encryption and lets you upload files of any size without manually splitting them; from version 0.2 it even lets you backup YouTube videos and channels.
Of course it has database file import/export feature.

Comment: I tested a bunch of stuff and it seems to work well. Of course the downside is that I would need to install it everywhere for it to work, but I would usually only use it on my laptop anyway.

Comment: Actually, I just now tried restoring files on another system than it has been uploaded to . That doesn't work at all. That makes it useless as a backup system, because if my system is broken and I re-install it, I can't access my files anymore.

Comment: What do you mean with "Of course it has database file import/export feature."? There is no such command in `--help` or in the Github description.

Comment: You can export backed up files list and credentials either directly copying the directory at `~/.config/pgpgram` to another user's home (be sure to have correct ownership for those file) or you can merge files backed up from another computer into current installation copying `~/.config/pgpgram/files.pkl` over and then giving `pgpgram --import files.pkl` (if you installed from `master` that won't probably work atm), it's in `--help` since 23 march commit. Master is not on PyPI because it saw introduced great performance features (when over 5.000 files) which broke `search` and `import` though.

Comment: Usually I do backups copying the directory on a flash drive and import files backed up from other devices to the main machine using `--import`.

Comment: But then why would I use Telegram at all if I need another medium to sync the information about what was uploaded? And I would need to find another solution to do that automatically, otherwise it's again a manual process.

Comment: I also use it as a secondary backup solution, that meaning that the tiny pickle file (now an sqlite db) is backed up along with my whole home directory on a physical machine. In general, the program was written to prove that Telegram needed a stronger privacy policy and probably didn't care for privacy all, so new features are only added when needed: since no one came forward asking for public key encryption you get why index rebuilding feature is missing.

Comment: That's also why `import` was added just a few months ago, why YouTube integration came out of the blue or why there is still no `delete` command lol. So, unless project gets funded in some way, you rely on other people needs. Merge requests and issue reporting are always welcomed, though.

Comment: Neverthless, there is no sign the program will be abandoned soon. Telegram is soaring, I heavily use it and the source is free as in free speech.

Answer (score -2):

Try

`telegram-desktop -sendpath <fullpath>`

Comment: How would that select a chat?

Comment: There seems to be such a command actually. But there is no documentation for it. If you know more, please comment here: https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/2058 But I'm pretty sure that just a path is not enough, how would it know what chat to send it to? I could actually try just putting a chat ID before or after the path, but that's just a random guess.

Comment: I have it running. You ask for help, get the proper and right answer and vote -1? O_o
Don't count on my help anymore

Comment: Well, how do you send to a specific chat? It can't just send it to a random chat. Do I need an ID, a name or something else? Where do I put that argument?

Comment: I tried it now. It's interactive, I'm supposed to click on a chat. That's not automatic and can't happen in the background. So this post does indeed not answer my queston.